# override S3 methods in base R

Tags: r, r-s3

I am attempting to over-ride the print.anova() function from the R stats package within a local package that I use when teaching.  Basically, I want to remove the printing of the heading and add a "total" row without creating a new function (e.g., ANOVA()) with a new class.

The function looks like the following:

```
print.anova <- function(x,digits=max(getOption("digits")-2,3),
 signif.stars=getOption("show.signif.stars"),totalSS=TRUE,rm.heading=TRUE,...) {
  if (!any(grepl("Res.Df",colnames(x)))) {         # exclusion for multiple lm objects
    if (!any(grepl("Levene",attr(x,"heading")))) { # exclusion for levenes.test
      if (totalSS) {                               # add total SS row
        x <- rbind(x,c(sum(x$Df),sum(x[,"Sum Sq"]),NA,NA,NA))
        row.names(x)[dim(x)[1]] <- "Total"
      }
    }
  }
  if (rm.heading) attr(x,"heading") <- NULL        # remove heading
  stats::print.anova(x,digits=digits,signif.stars=signif.stars,...)
  invisible(x)
}
```

My problem is that I am not sure whether to export this as a function, a method, an S3method, some combination of those, or something else entirely.  For example, when I try this (part of roxygenize code):

```
#'@export
```

I get the following warning when running Rcmd check:

```
S3 methods shown with full name in documentation object 'print.anova':
  'print.anova'
```

but the function works as expected when I load my package.

However, if I try this:

```
#'@method print anova
#'@S3method print anova
```

I dont' get any warnings or errors with Rcmd check but when I try to use the function in R it finds the original function in the stats package namespace.  Furthermore, if I do this

```
getAnywhere(print.anova)
```

I get this

```
2 differing objects matching ‘print.anova’ were found in the following places
  package:stats
  registered S3 method for print from namespace stats
  namespace:NCStats
  namespace:stats
```

Finally, for this version (not using export, but using method and S3method), my roxygen-developed namespace has the following item in it

```
S3method(print,anova)
```

Leading to my confusion is that I seem to have had success doing something similar with other functions (e.g., using the method and S3method version with print.summary.lm).

I would appreciate any help in my understanding what I am doing wrong here (or how I can ultimately accomplish this goal).  Thank you in advance for any help.

p.s., for what it is worth, I am on Windows 7 (32-bit), R 2.15.2, and using RStudio.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of trying to override the `print.anova` function you could create your own class which is essentially identical to the anova class. Create an `as.myanova` function which will turn an `anova` object into an object of `mynanova` then write your `print.myanova` function.

Comment: Use `class(anovaObject) <- c("myanova", "anova")` so you keep all the other methods for the anova object, and just replace those you want (i.e. print).